# Real-time signal processing in Python

Tags: python, signal-processing, real-time

I have to write a code which could process two signals (ECG and respiratory signal) real-time in Python. Specifically, this code should analyze respiration first, find the expiration phase and then process the ECG finding the R-peak. Any helpful suggestion/material/link? I have no idea how to do it. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, could you write, what you already tried, please? Maybe you could also add some more informations about, how you want to analyze respiration. This could increase the chances to get a helpfull answer. Please note, that most users here will not have medical background knowledge. Is this probably a machine learning related question?

Comment: I have a file.mat containg the breath's data. Signal is sampled at 100Hz and it is 22296 samples long. I was asked to implement a Python code which could process this type of signal real-time, in order to use it on future data acquisition sessions. My question is: how can  I check my code using this pre-recorded signal? I thought about reading sample by sample with a While true cycle from a csv file. Does it make sense?